# What justifies the existence of two independent rvs $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ that have the same distribution as some rvs $X$ and $Y$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, random-variables, fourier-analysis

What justifies the existence of two independent rvs $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ that have the same distribution as some rvs $X$ and $Y$

In the proof:

$X,Y$ are independent random variables $\iff$ $E[\exp(i\langle (t,s),(X,Y)\rangle)]=E[\exp(i\langle t,X\rangle)]E[\exp(i\langle s,Y\rangle)](*)$

for the $\Leftarrow$ part, I have seen a proof that uses the fact there exist independent random variables $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ with $X$ ~ $\overline{X}$ and $Y$ ~ $\overline{Y}$.

My question pertains to why it is always possible to find such independent random variables $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ that follow such a distribution. To me this assertion seems very far-reaching and I am having trouble to believe that we are always able to construct such an $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$. Any intuition or proofs?

Comment: This assertion may look far-reaching, but at the heart of things it is nothing but the product measure construction. Thinking of random variables in terms of the measures they induce on their respective sample spaces is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, where $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathcal{F}$ is Borel sets of $\Omega$ and $P=P_X\otimes P_Y$. Then let $\bar X=(s,t)=s$ and $\bar Y(s,t)=t$ for $(s,t)\in\Omega$.

Comment: Did you mean $\Omega = \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @zhoraster Indeed, thanks for catching that.